# Como identificar e contar colisão de prefabs na Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, jogos

Estou desenvolvendo um jogo para android na plataforma unity que é similar ao jogo Tetris, a diferença que é voltado para química, e ao invés de descer os tetrominos irá descer os elementos para compor uma molécula. Pois bem, qual o lógica que estou tentando aplicar: para formar uma carbono é preciso que o C tenho 4 H ao seu redor para fechar. Daí utilizei flags para os prefabs carbonos e para hidrogênios. A minha ideia é quando descer o C, verificar se existe o C, dai ele ira para as próximas condições, que é saber se tem um H em algum de seus lados, quando o contador chegar a 4 é pq o C fechou com os 4 H. Porem, nas pratica não funcionou. Alguém pode me ajudar com essa logica, ou da uma sugestão mais fácil? Na imagem abaixo o C esta composto por 4 H, dai era pra pontuar e deletar essas 5 peças(4 H e o C).

[image: erro]

ele nao ta fazendo as verificações;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E aqui está meu codigo:

```
public void Checks(){

    for (int y = 0; y < gridHeight; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; ++x) {
            if (Grid [x, y] != null) {

                if (Grid [x, y].tag == "CARBONO") {
                    Debug.Log ("EXISTE C: ");
                    if (Grid [x + 1, y].tag == "HIDROGENIO") {
                        cont++;
                    }
                    if (Grid [x - 1, y].tag == "HIDROGENIO") {
                        cont++;
                    }
                    if (Grid [x, y + 1].tag == "HIDROGENIO") {
                        cont++;
                    }
                    if (Grid [x, y - 1].tag == "HIDROGENIO") {
                        cont++;
                    }
                }
                Debug.Log ("contador: " + cont); //teste
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Classe GAME:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Game : MonoBehaviour {

public static int gridWidth = 10;
public static int gridHeight = 20;
public static Transform[,] Grid = new Transform[gridWidth, gridHeight];
public static Tetromino[,] model = new Tetromino[gridWidth, gridHeight];
private GameObject previewTetromino;
private GameObject nextTetromino;
private bool gameStarted = false;
public int scoreOneLine = 40;
public int scoreTwoLine = 100;
public int cont = 0;
private int numerOfRowsThisTurn = 0;
public Text hud_score;
public static int currentScore = 0;
private Vector2 previewTetrominoPosition = new Vector2 (13.88f, 11.08f);


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    SpawnNextTetromino ();


    //AudioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
} 

void Update () {
    Checks ();
    UpdateScore ();
    UpdateUI ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
public void UpdateScore(){
    if (numerOfRowsThisTurn > 0) {

        if (numerOfRowsThisTurn == 1) {
            ClearedOneLine ();
        } else if (numerOfRowsThisTurn == 2) {
            ClearedTwoLine ();
        }
        numerOfRowsThisTurn = 0;
    }
}

public void Checks(){

    for (int y = 0; y < gridHeight; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; ++x) {
            if (Grid [x, y] != null) {

                if (Grid [x, y].tag == "CARBONO") {
                    Debug.Log ("EXISTE C: ");
                    if (Grid [x + 1, y].tag == "HIDROGENIO") {
                        cont++;
                    }
                    if (Grid [x - 1, y].tag == "HIDROGENIO") {
                        cont++;
                    }
                    if (Grid [x, y + 1].tag == "HIDROGENIO") {
                        cont++;
                    }
                    if (Grid [x, y - 1].tag == "HIDROGENIO") {
                        cont++;
                    }
                }
                Debug.Log ("contador: " + cont); //teste
            }
        }
    }
}

public void UpdateUI(){
    hud_score.text = currentScore.ToString ();
}



public void ClearedOneLine(){
    currentScore += scoreOneLine;
}
public void ClearedTwoLine(){
    currentScore += scoreTwoLine;
}

public bool CheckIsAboveGrid(Tetromino tetromino){
    for(int x = 0; x < gridWidth; ++x){
        foreach(Transform mino in tetromino.transform){
            Vector2 pos = Round (mino.position);
            if(pos.y > gridHeight - 1){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public bool IsFullRowAt(int y){
    for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; ++x){
        if(Grid[x,y] = null){
            return false;
        }
    }
    numerOfRowsThisTurn++;
    return true;
}

public void updateGrid (Tetromino tetromino) {
    for (int y = 0; y <gridHeight; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x <gridWidth; ++x) {
            if (Grid [x, y] != null) {
                if (Grid [x, y].parent == tetromino.transform) {
                    Grid [x, y] = null;
                    model [x, y] = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    foreach (Transform mino in tetromino.transform) {
        Vector2 pos = Round (mino.position);
        if (pos.y < gridHeight) {
            Grid [(int)pos.x, (int)pos.y] = mino;
            model [(int)pos.x, (int)pos.y] = tetromino;
        }
    }
}
public Transform GetTransformAtGetPosition (Vector2 pos) {
    if (pos.y > gridHeight - 1) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return Grid [(int)pos.x, (int)pos.y];
    }

}

public void SpawnNextTetromino () {
    if (!gameStarted) {

        gameStarted = true;
        nextTetromino = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load(GetRandomTetromino(), typeof(GameObject)), new Vector2 (5.0f, 22.0f), Quaternion.identity);
        previewTetromino = (GameObject)Instantiate (Resources.Load (GetRandomTetromino (), typeof(GameObject)), previewTetrominoPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        previewTetromino.GetComponent<Tetromino> ().enabled = false;

    } else {
        previewTetromino.transform.localPosition = new Vector2 (5.0f, 20.0f);
        nextTetromino = previewTetromino;
        nextTetromino.GetComponent<Tetromino> ().enabled = true;

        previewTetromino = (GameObject)Instantiate (Resources.Load (GetRandomTetromino (), typeof(GameObject)), previewTetrominoPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        previewTetromino.GetComponent<Tetromino> ().enabled = false;
    }

}


public bool CheckIsInsideGrid (Vector2 pos){
    return ((int)pos.x >= 0 && (int)pos.x < gridWidth && (int)pos.y >= 0);
}

public Vector2 Round (Vector2 pos){
    return new Vector2 (Mathf.Round(pos.x), Mathf.Round(pos.y));
}

string GetRandomTetromino(){
    int randomTetromino = Random.Range (1, 5);
    string randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/C";
    switch (randomTetromino) {
    case 1:
        randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/H";

        break;
    case 2:
        randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/C";
        break;
    case 3:
        randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/H";
        break;
    case 4:
        randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/C";
        break;

    }
    return randomTetrominoName;


}
```

Classe TETROMINO:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Tetromino : MonoBehaviour {

float fall = 0;
public float fallSpeed = 2;
public bool allowRotation = true;
public bool limitRoatation = false;

public int individualScore = 100;
private float individualScoreTime;

public static int UP = 1;  
public static int DOWN = 2;
public static int RIGHT = 3;
public static int LEFT = 4;
private bool visited = false;
private bool fullConection = false;
private Tetromino[] connections = new Tetromino[4];


// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    CheckUserInput ();
    UpdateIndividualScore ();
}

public void UpdateIndividualScore(){

    if (individualScoreTime < 1) {

        individualScoreTime += Time.deltaTime;

    } else {

        individualScoreTime = 0;

        individualScore = Mathf.Max (individualScore - 10, 0);
    }
}
public void CheckUserInput () {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow)) {

                transform.position += new Vector3(1, 0, 0);

                if (CheckIsValidPosition()) {

                    FindObjectOfType<Game>().updateGrid(this);
                    FindObjectOfType<Game> ().Checks ();
                } else {

                    transform.position += new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);
                }

            } else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {

                transform.position += new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);

                if (CheckIsValidPosition()) {

                    FindObjectOfType<Game>().updateGrid(this);
                    FindObjectOfType<Game> ().Checks ();
                } else {

                    transform.position += new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
                }
            } else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)) {

                if (allowRotation) {

                    if (limitRoatation) {

                        if (transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z >= 90) {

                            //transform.Rotate(0, 0, -90);

                        } else {

                            //transform.Rotate(0, 0, 90);
                        }
                    } else {
                        transform.Rotate (0, 0, 90);
                    }

                    if (CheckIsValidPosition()) {

                        FindObjectOfType<Game>().updateGrid(this);
                        FindObjectOfType<Game> ().Checks ();
                    } else {

                        if (transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z >= 90) {

                            //transform.Rotate(0, 0, -90);

                        } else {
                            /*if (limitRoatation) {
                                transform.Rotate (0, 0, 90);

                            }*/

                            //transform.Rotate (0, 0, -90);
                        }
                    }
                }

            } else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow) || Time.time - fall >= fallSpeed) {

                transform.position += new Vector3(0, -1, 0);

                if (CheckIsValidPosition()) {

                    FindObjectOfType<Game>().updateGrid(this);
                    //FindObjectOfType<Game> ().Checks ();

                } else {

                    transform.position += new Vector3(0, 1, 0);

                    if (FindObjectOfType<Game> ().CheckIsAboveGrid (this)) {
                        FindObjectOfType<Game> ().GameOver ();
                    }

                    enabled = false;


                    FindObjectOfType<Game> ().updateConnection (this);
                    FindObjectOfType<Game> ().Checks ();
                    FindObjectOfType<Game> ().SpawnNextTetromino ();

                    Game.currentScore += individualScore;


                }

                fall = Time.time;
            }
        }

bool CheckIsValidPosition () {

    foreach (Transform mino in transform) {

    Vector2 pos = FindObjectOfType<Game>().Round (mino.position);

    if (FindObjectOfType<Game>().CheckIsInsideGrid (pos) == false) {

            return false;
        }

        if (FindObjectOfType<Game>().GetTransformAtGetPosition(pos) != null && FindObjectOfType<Game>().GetTransformAtGetPosition(pos).parent != transform) {

            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Dê mais detalhes de como vc já fez o projeto. Por exemplo, você está usando a física da Unity (tipo, os elementos "caem" usando a física, ou vc faz translação manualmente?)? Dependendo da sua abordagem, há diferentes possíveis respostas/sugestões.

Comment: Para que lhe possa ajudar, é necessário mais informação tal como disse o @LuizVieira.

Comment: Apenas uma sugestão, sempre que quiser uma sequencia de acontecimento, aconselho a fazer o script da seguinte forma:
if(Grid [x + 1, y].tag == "HIDROGENIO" && Grid [x - 1, y].tag == "HIDROGENIO" etc etc etc) colocando um AND lógico, para que o script tenha a capacidade de apenas executar quando todas as condições sejam satisfeitas.
Mas mais uma vez relembro a falta de informações de forma a que lhe possa ajudar.

Comment: Bom galera, eu faço com que as peças caiam sem a fisica da engine. Como voces podem ver no codigo acima.

Comment: Toda a base do meu jogo ate o momento foi seguido por esse tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aurEgWxDfQQ&list=PLiRrp7UEG13axMHD7Kqdiy30c7ZBu_Zn7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Antes de sugerir um algoritmo para tratar o que de fato vc precisa, vou tomar a liberdade de oferecer algumas dicas que podem ajudar você a talvez até a outro futuro leitor:

1. **Use comentários**. O seu código praticamente não tem nenhum comentário sobre o que ele faz. Tudo bem, pode ser um estilo seu de programar. Só que isso dificulta que outra pessoa entenda o que você produziu. Dificulta até a sua própria manutenção futura, uma vez que é comum de nós mesmos esquecermos dos detalhes do que fizemos após um longo período sem trabalhar no projeto. Você poderia comentar nos métodos, indicando pra que eles servem ou o que fazem, e ao menos nos atributos das classes para indicar pra que eles servem/são usados.
2. **Organize o código**. O seu código também está um pouco bagunçado. Novamente, cada um tem seu estilo. Mas a identação não serve só para estética: ela facilita a leitura e facilita encontrar onde estão definidas as coisas.
3. **Use bem a Orientação a Objetos**. A OO existe por um princípio importante: ela facilita o raciocínio sobre o problema. Se você não a segue, perde a vantagem em utilizá-la. Tá, nem todo mundo entende profundamente esses conceitos, mas não custa dar uma estudada né? No seu caso, por exemplo, você coloca comportamentos que deveriam ser da peça que se move (que eu julgo seja o tal do Tetrominó) na classe que controla o jogo. O comportamento de verificação de formação de moléculas pode parecer fazer mais sentido na classe do jogo, mas não é o último Tetrominó que se move que é capaz de formar uma molécula (afinal, os outros que já estão empilhados não formaram nada ainda, porque se o tivessem já teriam sumido e se transformado em pontos, certo?). Um indicador de que há problemas ai é o fato de que *há código* na classe do Tetrominó que frequentemente invoca métodos da classe do Jogo (o método `check`, por exemplo).

Bom, sobre a sua solução, o colega @SoeiroMass [deu uma dica bacana](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136055/como-identificar-e-contar-colis%C3%A3o-de-prefabs-na-unity#comment283635_136055). Mas supondo que você não vai ter só esses dois elementos (hidrogênio e carbono), esse tipo de verificação vai ficar inviável. O que eu sugiro é que você programe, *na clase do Tetrominó*, um mecanismo de lista que mantenha os elementos vizinhos (isto é, já conectados). Assim, dado um Tetrominó qualquer será possível consultar dele (via uma chamada de método do tipo `getNeighbours`) quais elementos já estão conectados a ele.

Essa lista vai ser mantida *por cada um dos Tetrominós individualmente*, a partir da sua ["detecção de colisão"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CI_Yr8iA3RM). Para isso, adicione um colisor da Unity e defina-o como "trigger" (já que vc não precisa da física e faz a translação manualmente). Então, crie o método `OnTriggerEnter2D` (estou supondo que o seu jogo é 2D) para capturar o evento na classe do Tetrominó. Observe que cada elemento vai receber esse evento, já que todos têm os seus colisores/triggers. Assim, quando A colidir com B, A vai adicionar B à sua lista, e B vai adicionar A à sua lista.

Uma vez tendo essa lista e um método de acesso à ela, você pode fazer a classe Game receber um evento (um aviso via chamada de método serve mesmo) *quando o Tetrominó atualmente caindo parar*. Ele é o único que interessa do ponto de vista do jogo, já que somente ele é capaz de construir uma moléculá válida (certo? Afinal, se os outros já posicionados tivessem moléculas válidas, eles já teriam sido "tratados" pelo jogo). O jogo então solicita a lista de vizinhos e compara-a com um template. Esse template serve pra você saber se a união de vizinhos forma algo real (a molécula de Carbono, por exemplo), e pode ser mantida em um arquivo de configuração lido e acessado idealmente por outra classe específica pra isso. Há diversas formas de implementar esse template e sua comparação. Uma delas é ter uma soma de caracteres simples. Supondo que cada elemento tenha um identificador que é a letra dele (i.e. `C`, `H`, etc), as combinações deles também serão strings simples de contar (i.e. `CHHH` ou `HCHH`, etc). De fato, essa string com as letras pode ser o que retorna o método de consulta aos vizinhos, e fica ainda mais fácil de comparar com o template se ao montar essa string a ordem das letras for garantidamente alfabética.

Comment: Luiz Vieira me passa teu facebook pra entrar em contato com vc

Comment: Carlos, se o seu objetivo é tirar dúvidas pontuais, eu sugiro usar o [chat]. :) Agora, se vc tem outras dúvidas que podem ser úteis pra outras pessoas, abra uma nova pergunta. Este site não é um fórum, ok? Se não fez ainda, faça o [tour].

Comment: Gostaria de usar o chat, como abrir o chat com vc?

Comment: Luiz adicionei os colisores aos meus objetos e implementei o metodo de colisao na classe tetromino, agora estou com duvida nessa lista de vizinhos e comparar com um template. Voce tem algum exemplo que possa me passar? Ou me ajudar a implementar esse metodo? Estou começando agora em unity e nao tenho muita experiencia. Desde ja agradeço

Comment: Oi Carlos. Aqui tem algumas dicas pra chamar alguém para um chat: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2175/73 Só que eu tinha mais sugerido de vc tentar encontrar *qualquer pessoa* lá pra te ajudar pontualmente. Como vc deve ter percebido pela minha demora, infelizmente eu tô bem ocupado hoje e não vou conseguir muito tempo pra te ajudar. :/

Comment: Sobre listas/arrays de objetos, faça um tutorial. Tem um montão disponivel na Internet. Tipo esse: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-mee0meDDvE Sugiro também o canal do @Nils: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kzCRhK6x4KQ&list=PLa2bQ5uCFWA1RNqmaQIAWiq5HiWUGATyC